# Using Java Scripting API to create game content

Tags: java, javascript, performance, scripting

So, I'll be using the Java Scripting API with JavaScript to do all the scripting for the game. Now, I've read over the documentation I can't seem to figure out how I could do a one time run of some of the scripts to get all the 'different types of objects data' to be fed to Java. I'm actually not quite sure how to save all that data to Java or if I should even try saving it to Java....

QUESTION: **How can I import a bunch of scripting information at run-time into my application?**

Answer (score 0):

You can basically pass data between scripting environment and Java through the scripting API. For example,

```
    final ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    final ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

    engine.eval("greeting='Hello'");
    // Returning data from scripting environment to Java.
    // The data can also be returned from a function
    final String greeting = (String) engine.eval("greeting");
    System.out.println(greeting); //prints Hello

    //Passing data to scripting environment from Java
    engine.put("who", "foo");
    final String greetingFoo = (String) engine.eval("greeting + ', ' + who");
    System.out.println(greetingFoo); //prints Hello, foo
```

Comment: Hmm, okay. I just need to figure out how to generate all the different types of classes in java at run-time. That'll be interesting. Like I have to use all the JavaScript to create the AIs and block types and such.